# Can first-order logic be recognized by a pushdown automaton?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, context-free-grammar, parsing

I have the belief that first-order logic cannot be recognized by a pushdown automaton because the automaton will have no way to keep track of the variables that are currently in scope. More precisely, I have the belief that the language of well-formed formulas of first-order logic, in its usual formulation, with say finitely many non-logical symbols, cannot be recognized by a pushdown automaton because the automaton will have no way to keep track of the numerals which index all the variables that are currently in scope.

I also have the belief that the difficulty is not essential, and that first-order logic could be reformulated, using harmless tricks, in a format that could be recognized by a pushdown automaton. My difficulty is that I do not know how to define "harmless" correctly.

Obviously, the well-formed formulas of first-order logic can be put recursively into one-to-one correspondence with the unary numerals, and in this new "formulation" the well-formed formulas are very easy to recognize. It seems, however that doing any real work with such well-formed formulas would need to pass through a preliminary translation step by a machine more powerful than I would like.

The logic textbooks I consult (for example, Marker) consider these issues to be fiddly details that be safely mishandled. Where can I go to learn about these fiddly details?

Comment: The usual definition of "well-formed formula" does not care about the scope of variables at all...

Comment: That's a good point. Maybe I don't just want to recognize the first-order formulas, I want to parse them in some meaningful way.

Comment: The computer science literature is probably a better place to look. Clearly, implementing programs that manipulate formulas requires dealing with all the details, fiddly or otherwise. On the other hand, usually matching the "syntax" of formulas is (conceptually) handled separately from validating scoping. You may want to look at [de Bruijn notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_notation) and at [nested data types for well-scoped formulas](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0956796899003366).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Given two words (in a fixed alphabet), do you want to recognize if they are well-formed formulas and equal up to renaming of bound variables?